# Chrome extension options page minimized unless move away from tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-extension

Upon switching to Chrome's Manifest 3 format (and per its requirements, using a service worker if that's somehow relevant), my options page shows up like this:

[image]

Only upon moving away from the tab and reentering it, do I get my options to show up:

[image]

It doesn't matter if I trigger the options page via the toolbar or via its extensions entry.

I do have the options page in the manifest file, so I wouldn't think the change to a service worker has relevance. I don't have any listeners for the page visibility API.

Even when I blank out my options code with a minimum of content and update the unpacked extension, I still experience this behavior.

Any configuration or behaviors that could be triggering this (and how to overcome)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whatever the cause of this behavior, that it only occurs when loading an unpacked extension. When I use `web-ext` to build a zip file and open that in Chrome, I don't see this problem.

Not ideal, but a bug I can at least live with.